# SQL Server is not started

Tags: sql-server, windows-8

I created the local service. My server name is like `sqlitesync.com`. In my database folder created the `configuration (web.config)` and `WCF web service (AuroraSyncService.svc)`. When I test this service in browser it shows nothing.

i followed this tutorial [Link](http://sqlite-sync.com/documentation/installation/)

When start the service http://sqlitesync.com/sqlitesyncservice/AuroraSyncService.svc in browser it shows the empty like [image]

When I create my own (`index.html`) `http://sqlitesync.com/index.html` it works fine

[image: http://sqlitesync.com/index.html]

I don't know how to solve this also I am new to SQL Server.

Anybody provide a solution to solve this..

configuration code:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AuroraSyncCn" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SQLite-Sync.com;User ID=***;Password=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server did you install? Are you sure the service is running? Check the Services applet in the Control Panel or SQL Server Configuration Manager. Testing if SQL Server is running using a web browser does not seem like a practical or reliable test to me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Microsoft SQL server 2012 v 11.1.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i followed this tutorial http://sqlite-sync.com/documentation/installation/   i got struck in Database restore steps...